# PHP not storing the date in MySQL table column

Tags: php, html, mysql, date, timestamp

I'm having a problem storing the date correctly in a MySQL database table under the column name 'publicationDate' via an html form.

```
 //  Contruct Of The Data
public function __construct($data=array()) {
if (isset($data['id'])) $this->id = (int) $data['id'];
if (isset($data['publicationDate'])) $this->publicationDate = (int) $data['publicationDate'];
if (isset($data['content'])) $this->content = $data['content'];
}

// Values To Post/Store For The Webpage Forms 
public function storeFormValues ($params) {
 $this->__construct($params);
 if (isset($params['publicationDate'])) {
   $publicationDate = explode ('-', $params['publicationDate']);
  if (count($publicationDate) == 3) {
    list ($y, $m, $d) = $publicationDate;
    $this->publicationDate = mktime (0, 0, 0, $m, $d, $y);
   }
  }
 }
```

The My SQL Column 'publicationDate' datatype is 'TIMESTAMP()' 'NOT NULL' default 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'. the date is to be stored & formatted '0000-00-00 00:00:00'.

The HTML form input for 'publicationDate' which is an edit form that is hidden and not to be edited is as:

```
<input type="hidden" name="publicationDate" id="publicationDate" value="<?php if ($results['article']->id ==true) { echo date("Y-m-d g:i:s", $results['article']->publicationDate);} else { echo date("Y-m-d g:i:s");}?>"/>
```

It'll store the date like this - '0000-00-00 00:00:00' which is 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss' but only the year, month, & day will show correctly. The hour, minutes, & seconds will always appear in MySQL all zeros (00:00:00). This is obviously a problem when display/listing my data 'DESC' which is of course most recent being at the top of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want the `mysql` date format to be 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss' you need to change the `php` date format.

Change `date("Y-m-d g:i:s"` into `date("Y-m-d H:i:s"` in both instances.

The `g` format displays the hour in 12-hour format of an hour without leading zeros
while the `H` format displays the hour in 24-hour format with leading zeros.

Also when you construct the `$publicationDate` you create it with with hour=0, minute=0, second=0.

If you want to populate the `$publicationDate` with the time of the form's submission use this:

`$publicationDate = mktime(date('H'), date('i'), date('s'), $m, $d, $y);`

This will take the current hour, minute and second and the submitted month, day and year from the user.

You should actually assign actual times in your `storeFormValues function.

See here manual for [mktime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php)

Comment: How would I change adjust it this because I tried many changes with many different results. An example being that it'll store it 1969-12-31 00:00:00). I have no idea why I would be getting this result with the different changes I've tried.

Comment: I did change the date in the 24-hour format but it's still not storing the hours for some reason. I believe it's in the 'storemformValues' function using mktime ().

Comment: I've been messing around with this for a long time and it's driving me crazy.

Comment: are you actually getting the hour, min, sec values from the html form?

Comment: I updated my answer to allow current time plus submitted date

Comment: @ Alex Andrei - It worked great. I appreciate the help very much. Also I see now why storing it in the 24-Hour format makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation for the PHP date function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) the g in g:i:s would be 12-hour format of an hour without leading zeros. It needs to be H, which is 24-hour format of an hour with leading zeros.

Comment: I changed this and still recieve the same results when storing the date.